# Finding perimeter of a recursively modified square

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a square of side length 1 . Now, after each second, each square of side L will break into four squares each of side L/2.

[image]

I need the compute the total perimeter of the resulting figure, where total perimeter is defined as the sum of lengths of all line segments in the resulting figure. For example, the total perimeter of the image on the left is `4L` while that on the right is `6L` - `4L` from the regular square edges and `2L` from the internal line segments.

My code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define mod 1000000007

int main() {



        int s;
        cin>>s;
       long long  int ans=4;

        for(int i=1;i<=s;i++)
            ans+=1<<i;
            ans=ans%mod;

        cout<<ans<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Since the final answer might not fit in a 64-bit signed integer, I am required to compute the answer modulo `1000000007`.

**For example, after 0 seconds, the length is 4. 
After 1 second, the length is 6.**
I am not getting the correct output. PLease help

Comment: @MikeSeymour since the length is 1 , and i have initally taken ans=4

Comment: Show an example what you expect to be shown if the program was correct.

Comment: @PreetSangha i am getting wrong answer with this approach , i am requesting where i have committed mistake

Comment: The line 'ans=ans%mode;' is not necessary.

Comment: I think you want to calculate perimeter after n seconds.

Comment: Apart from that weird modular reduction (which will give the wrong answer for very large input values), I can't see anything wrong. Assuming the result is supposed to be the total length of all the lines. What output are you getting, and what do you expect?

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia yes perimeter of all the squares

Comment: @MikeSeymour the answers are in the form of %mod

Comment: @user4115692: So (a) what exactly is the problem you're solving (the problem statement doesn't mention any modular reduction) and (b) what output are you getting, and what do you expect?

Comment: Pleas can you explain  "after 0 seconds, the length is 4. After 1 second, the length is 6"

Comment: @user966379 see figure 1 i.e at 0 sec perimeter 4 see figure 2 after 1 sec total perimeter of all squares 6

Comment: Got it. I answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve it recursively - let `P(L, n)` be the "perimeter" of the figure obtained after `n` iterations, starting with an `LxL` square. So, `P(L, n+1) = 4*P(L/2,n) - 2*L`. Also, since the perimeter is linear, `P(L/2, n) = P(L, n)/2`, giving you `P(L,n) = 2*P(L,n-1) - 2*L`. Substitute `L=1` and run your loop.

```
   int s;
   cin>>s;
   long long  int ans=4;

   for(int i=1;i<=s;i++)
   {
        ans = 2*(ans-1);
        ans=ans%mod;
   }
```

Comment: @user4115692 if the recursion works out to what you have coded up, then the issue would be with overflow in `1<<s`. You should make your `i` `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

The perimeter after s seconds will be : 4+2(2^s-1)
So,

```
int main()
{
    int s;
    cout << "Enter Time: ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Perimeter = " << (4 + 2 * (pow( 2, s ) - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an undivided square. When you split the square into 4 equal squares, you are essentially adding half of the initial perimeter. The outer walls of the original square are included as is in the new perimeter, and add to that the length of the 2 lines drawn inside it, the length of each of which is equal to the side of the square.

    `noOfsqaures = 1;
    oldSide = 1; //one sqaure of side 1
    oldPerimeter = 4*oldSide;
    loop for the number of seconds
        newPerimeter = oldPerimeter + 2*oldSide*noOfSquares
        oldSide = oldSide/2; //for the next iteration
        oldPermiter = newPermeter //for the next iteration
        noOfSquares = noOfSquares*4;`

Answer (score 0):

o/p:   4(initial value) +
    2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + ...

I think it would help you for coding. If you need I will give you code

```
for(int i=1;i<=s;i++)
{
  ans+=1<<i;
}
```